# Signalr with Aspx Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

I am working on a project which is a asp.net application by using c# 4.5. I am trying to implement signalr into my project. So far when i use it in html, i can send the request and can get the response into JavaScript from server side. But my application structure is based on master pages and web forms with master page. I define the paths of the required scripts correctly (which i have already tested by using in html and working well). When i run the app, scripts are running and an error occurs such as

> 0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'serverHub' of undefined or null reference

serverHub is the

> var serverSide = $.connection.serverHub;

creating a proxy but this error averts me to keep going on. So far what i have seen from the examples for the signalr, all of them is done in a html page. So here is my question;
SignalR is being used just only in html? if it is no then am i able to use it in aspx pages like i explained above, how can i do this?

Thank you so much for your helps in advance and will be waiting for your any supportive ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take a look on this article :

http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr

When you try to use signalR in your project don't forget to map signalr on startup, for example :

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.MapSignalR();
    }
}
```

Comment: In that article they use a html page and what i want to know is that is it possible to use in aspx page? i know that we can use signalr in mvc project with cshtml extension but is it possible for aspx too?

Comment: Yes its possible without any issue ;)